# display math in GoogleColab

Tags: python, widget, latex, google-colaboratory, display

Can someone explain me why the code below works in Jupyter (the string is updated and displayed when modified by the widget) but does not work in GoogleColab ? (And how to make it works in GoogleColab ?)

```
from IPython.display import display, Math

def combustion(nH2i,nO2i,nH2Oi):
    x = nH2i/2      
    if nO2i-x<0:    
        x = nO2i    

    nH2f = nH2i - 2*x
    nO2f =  nO2i - x
    nH2Of = nH2Oi + 2*x
    
    reponse = r"""$\begin{array}{cccc}
    2.H_2&+&O_2&\to&2.H_2O\\
    {nH2i}&+&{nO2i}&&{nH2Oi}\\
    {nH2f}&+&{nO2f}&&{nH2Of}\\
    \end{array}$"""
    liste = ["nH2i","nO2i","nH2Oi","nH2f","nO2f","nH2Of"]
    for x in liste:
        reponse = reponse.replace(x,str(eval(x)))
    display(Math(reponse))

from ipywidgets import interact
interact(combustion, nH2i=(0,10,1), nO2i=(0,10,1), nH2Oi=(0,10,1))
```

Edit:
It doesn't work because it prints the uninterpreted LaTeX string (as shown in Mark comment) but it doesn't display it as a LaTeX interpeter should do: an array with the values !

Comment: for me it seems to work in both (if this is what you're meant to see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTx3C.png

Comment: What doesn't work exactly? [ask] and [mre]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display LaTeX strings in Colab, you can utilize third-party libraries. The simplest approach is to employ the [mathjax](https://www.mathjax.org/) library. To achieve this, you need to execute the following code in the preceding cells:

```
from IPython.display import display, HTML, Math

def load_mathjax():
    display(HTML("<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.3/"
                 "latest.js?config=default'></script>"))
    display(Math(""))  # This line is neccessary. Do not remove it!

get_ipython().events.register('pre_run_cell', load_mathjax)
```

After that, I obtained the following result from executing your code in Colab:

[image]